# subscribe 2 different Observable and onNext both of them?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

Given I subscribe to 2 different Observables and I want get both of them on onNext after do some operations to them

let's say I have 2 Observables

```
Observable<List<String>> childName = Observable.from(children)... some operations
Observable<List<String>> teacherName = Observable.from(teachers)... some operations
```

how do I get both of them on my subscribe?

```
subscribe( 
    onNext(List<String> childName, List<String> className)
```

so that I can pass both of them in my listener in that manner.

I don't want to combine them, I just want when after the operations are finished, get both of them and pass it on my subscriptions

Comment: use flatMap to combine them, instead of doing it in your listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `zip` their values into a `Pair`:

```
Observable.zip(childName, className, 
    (a, b) -> Pair.of(a, b))
.subscribe((Pair<List<String>, List<String>> pair) -> {
    // do something with pair.first and pair.second
}, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: What object is Pair? is it an android component? the code is in my presenter so I cannot have android component inside the presenter

Comment: For example: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html but you can write your own quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

hacky but simple

```
Observable.zip(childName, teacherName, (childList, teachersList) -> {
    // handle childList & teachersList
    return Observable.empty();
}).subscribe(o -> {}, error -> {
    //handle errors
});
```